# Python detect headset button press

Tags: python, io, headset

I just need simple library that detect headset button state.

So I expect there simple program like this.

```
from hsbutton import isPressed

while True:
  if isPressed():
    Print("You are clicking headset button")
  else:
    Print("Waiting click")
```

Edit:
Tbh I don't know the difference of headset and earphone so I show you the picture.
In that picture you can see I circled a button. That button is what I mean.
[image]